# Remote connection solution and cut & paste monitoring

Tags: security, ssh, solaris, clipboard, remote-access

Guys I've been asked to evaluate a few remote connection solutions for my small company (linux & solaris, but could go for a solaris only solution).

One of the more difficult requirements (for me...) is that cut & paste between remote and local system has to be monitored.

I short listed 3 possible solutions:

- Sun Secure Global Desktop
- Citrix
- X tunnelling through SSH

Thing is I don't know any of these will let me monitor cut & paste flow. Any ideas? Any other solutions that will give me that level of control?

Or if it's a lost battle, can you just disable cut & paste?

Comment: You're going to have better luck with this question over on ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Posted there (http://serverfault.com/questions/225822/remote-connection-solution-and-cut-paste-monitoring)

Comment: On Sun Secure Global Desktop, you can indeed disable cut & paste, or even limit it to subsets of users, or specific applications.

Comment: May be Synergy can help: http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental control of Cut and Paste on a Linux or Solaris desktop is managed by 
X Windows. This means that the Desktop Manager (GNOME, KDE) doesn't matter.

X Windows tunneling through ssh will not have any impact on cut and paste. X Windows tunneling though ssh just allows you to run X Windows from a remote server on your local desktop and protect that connection between them.

Citrix provides an X Windows server and client applications. I do not know the administrative capabilities of Citrix products. Neither do I know the administrative capabilities of Sun Secure Global Desktop.

X Windows gives you a way to monitor X Windows events: XSelectInput. X Windows cut and paste is implemented in to different types of selection: Primary and clipboard. So by monitoring those events you can collect the buffer contents. I found a [perl script] (https://github.com/trapd00r/clipbored/blob/95b33c547a84eb2e13e51557fcc95641e003acd6/clipbored) which monitors the buffer using the xclip utility.

It gets more complicated. GNOME and KDE both have clipboards for copying and pasting. So you would have to monitor those too.

The important question to ask is what you hope to achieve with copy and paste monitoring and what will it cost. I don't think you can deter employees from intentionally copying sensitive information with cut and past monitoring. There are several obvious circumvention mechanisms: e-mail, USB flash drive, print out to paper, burn to CD, mobile device (phone, mp3 player, etc). And the employees will dislike and resent this monitoring or restriction. Their dissatisfaction and resentment is also a cost to factor in here. You may use copy and paste monitoring to detect the unintentional copying of sensitive information, but then what are you going to do once you have detected it?